# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_resource() in Zend/Log/Writer/Stream.php line 115

Tags: magento-1.6

Magento has been really slow and unresponsive lately for me.
Sometimes restarting the server solves it, but the problem reoccurs after a few good minutes.

Here's what I found in error.log (apache2).
A lot of those fatal errors:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function is_resource() in /home/sites/billyguyatts.com.au/docs/lib/Zend/Log/Writer/Stream.php on line 115

Could someone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: Can you please add a stacktrace for this?

Comment: Interesting, same error for me, no stack trace in the log either. I was hitting the server kinda hard last night, but this error seems pretty bizarre! Nothing wrong w/ the PHP install afaict...

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP seems badly broken?!

The function `is_resource` exists since PHP4, so I have no idea why this error occurs, but I think you are in bug trouble.

I tried googling for "Call to undefined function is_resource()" but there is nothing to find, so I would say this is no PHP bug.

So if it is no PHP bug, then you might have a hardware problem?

Comment: Exactly - error is based on a PHP function, so likely not the culprit.  Have you got enough disk space on the server?

Comment: Douglas, there are more disk space than we require.

Comment: The CPU usage has been 100% on all 6 of them, which might be why everything's slowed down. I can't find the reason why it's using 100% CPUs (most of them apache2 processes) MaxClients lowered from 80 to 40 for testing purposes and still same problem.

Comment: Fabian, could you show me how to do a stracktrace for this ?

Comment: Wherever your error comes from should normally the stack trace just behind. Maybe xdebug adds this to my environment.